# N-ary trees - is it symmetric or not

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

Given an N-ary tree, find out if it is symmetric about the line drawn through the root node of the tree. It is easy to do it in case of a binary tree. However for N-ary trees it seems to be difficult

Comment: What do you see as adding substantial difficulty in analyzing an N-ary tree? The only part I can see that's difficult is basically a matter for an arbitrary decision: given that the root node can have N descendants, exactly how do you decide which of those to consider to the left and to the right of "the line"?

Answer (score 6):

One way to think about this problem is to notice that a tree is symmetric if it is its own reflection, where the reflection of a tree is defined recursively:

1. The reflection of the empty tree is itself.
2. The reflection of a tree with root r and children c1, c2, ..., cn is the tree with root r and children reflect(cn), ..., reflect(c2), reflect(c1).

You can then solve this problem by computing the tree's reflection and checking if it's equal to the original tree.  This again can be done recursively:

1. The empty tree is only equal to itself.
2. A tree with root r and children c1, c2, ..., cn is equal to another tree T iff the other tree is nonempty, has root r, has n children, and has children that are equal to c1, ..., cn in that order.

Of course, this is a bit inefficient because it makes a full copy of the tree before doing the comparison.  The memory usage is O(n + d), where n is the number of nodes in the tree (to hold the copy) and d is the height of the tree (to hold the stack frames in the recursion tom check for equality).  Since d = O(n), this uses O(n) memory.  However, it runs in O(n) time since each phase visits each node exactly once.

A more space-efficient way of doing this would be to use the following recursive formulation:

```
1. The empty tree is symmetric.
2. A tree with n children is symmetric if the first and last children are mirrors, the second and penultimate children are mirrors, etc.
```

You can then define two trees to be mirrors as follows:

1. The empty tree is only a mirror of itself.
2. A tree with root r and children c1, c2,..., cn is a mirror of a tree with root t and children d1, d2, ..., dn iff r = t, c1 is a mirror of dn, c2 is a mirror of dn-1, etc.

This approach also runs in linear time, but doesn't make a full copy of the tree.  Comsequently, the memory usage is only O(d), where d is the depth of the tree.  This is at worst O(n) but is in all likelihood much better.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do an in-order tree traversal( node left right) on the left sub-tree and save it to a list. Then do another in-order tree traversal (node right left) on the right sub-tree and save it to a list. Then, you can just compare the two lists. They should be the same.

Comment: Your reply somehow assumes symmetrical is referring to data as opposed to structure. For an easier visual: a BST is symmetrical if the following is true: boolean hasStructuralSymmetry(Node a, Node b) {
    if (null == a && null == b)
      return true;
    if (null == a || null == b)
      return false;
    return hasStructuralSymmetry(a.left, b.right)
            && areIdentical(a.right, b.left);} copied from http://geekviewpoint.com/BST_code_in_Java/

Answer (score 0):

Take a stack
Now each time start traversing through root node, 
now recursively call a function and push the element of left sub tree one by one at a particular level.
maintain a global variable and update its value each time a left sub tree is pushed onto the stack.now call recursively(after recursive call to left sub tree)the right sub and pop on each correct match.doing this will ensure that it is being checked in symmetric manner.

At the end if stack is empty ,i.e. all elements are processed and each element of stack has been popped out..you are through!

Answer (score 0):

One more way to answer this question is to look at each level and see if each level is palindrome or not. For Null nodes, we can keep adding dummy nodes with any value which is unique.

Answer (score -1):

It's not difficult.  I'm going to play golf with this question.  I got 7... anyone got better?

```
data Tree = Tree [Tree]
symmetrical (Tree ts) =
    (even n || symmetrical (ts !! m)) &&
    all mirror (zip (take m ts) (reverse $ drop (n - m) ts))
    where { n = length ts; m = n `div` 2 }
mirror (Tree xs, Tree ys) =
    length xs == length ys && all mirror (zip xs (reverse ys))
```